# Result don't print that table was created

Tags: sql, oracle

i reinstall the oracle to 11g and there is one problem. For exapmple when i create a table there is nothing in result, in 12c was message that "CREATED TABLE %tablename%", now there is nothing. In the blue corner written that create 
table statemant was proceed

[image: Image of sql Developer]

Comment: is this part of plsql block ? or in a specific editor ?

Comment: i dont know. I just connect a database oracle in sql developer and create tables. But after reinstall there is no output about created or droped and other. But can see Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but in your screen is opened tab `RESULT` and not `OUTPUT`